# unbale to get a page with CURL php

Tags: php, curl, cookies, cloudflare

I want try to get a page from a website with curl, this is example of what I want to do

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, './cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, './cookies.txt');
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.dwarozh.net/details.aspx?jimare=37170",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
?>
```

But I faced with **Please enable cookies.**

[image]

It seems Sucuri of *CloudFlare* prevent  CURL to get content of that page, **My question is how can I bypass Cloudflare verification and get access to pages markups with PHP?**

**Note** a `cookie.txt` file created automatically by curl in Current Php Directory with below contents:

```
#Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_.dwarozh.net  TRUE    /   FALSE   1512737114  __cfduid    d2074a34e7e0222605c50752e3c5080a81481201114
```

Comment: @PeeHaa the question you find as duplicate, still hasn't accepted answer, and also my question is difference with, before mark some question as duplicated please read it carefully, sometimes questions maybe be similar but difference

Comment: Considering you didn't explain what you think is different *or* what the result was of the implementation of the answers over there nor explaining why they didn't work for you I don't see why it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @PeeHaa if you take a look at response image you can see it return **please enable cookie**.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the user agent string in the CURL_SETOPT? It could be that cloudflare is blocking based on that.
Try curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)");

Comment: I try this but still the same . **Please enable cookies.**

Comment: it's not working dear :(